# Can't import Class_ in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to use Criteria Api for for making queries on database. I found this article:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

The problem is this code :

```
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet_);
```

I can't import Pet_ class. Do i need to create that class or?

This is my code:

```
public class DnevnikFacade extends AbstractFacade<Dnevnik> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "zadaca_4_1PU")
    private EntityManager em;
    CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery;
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
    private Root <Dnevnik> dnevnik ;
    private List<Predicate> filteri;


    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
        dnevnik = criteriaQuery.from(Dnevnik.class);
        return em;
    }

    public DnevnikFacade() {
        super(Dnevnik.class);
    }

    public List<Dnevnik> dohvatiDnevnikPremaFilterima(){
        criteriaQuery.select(dnevnik).where(filteri.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
        return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }
    public void filterStatus(String status){
    filteri.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(dnevnik.get(Dnevnik_.status), status));

    }

}
```

And that Dnevnik_status is the problem. Status is a column in table Dnevnik. What am i doing wrong, can somebody help me?
what does that class_ mean? How can i resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: The JPA "_" static metamodel classes need to be created, normally by calling one of the JPA provider annotation processors (as a pre-compile step). For example http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#metamodel   Have you done that?